# How do you recover a wordpress site with no username or password?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a Wordpress site that was built by a developer before me at my job. They did not give me a username or password or any information on this and I cannot access this site. I can't find a backup, old password, or anything. Wordpress customer service is literally useless. Does anyone know of a way to recover an account with literally no information?

I have tried contacting customer service (useless- since they are run by volunteers), tried looking for a backup in the drive (doesn't exist), tried multiple variations of what the username/password could be, tried asking around the company (nobody knows). Company wants the site updated, but obviously I can't do this if I cant even access the back-end of the site. I am thinking I may need to replicate the entire site if I can't recover it which is looking more likely.

Comment: Been there. Done this. It's a pain in the neck. Your next stop should be figuring out what hosting company hosts the site. On Windows give this command line `tracert example.com` .  On other OSs give `traceroute example.com` .   (Put your own host name in place of `example.com` and don't include `https://` or any other web browser stuff.)  The last few lines of output should show some hostnames giving you a clue who the hosting company is. Then maybe you can persuade that hosting company to grant you access. Plan on getting an official letter from your CEO / Executive Director.